# How to post simple text to FB wall programmatically using HTML?

Tags: facebook

What I'd like to do is to post some simple text to a user's FB wall (with the user's ID already known to my app).

Have read quite a few posts about posting to FB wall, however, still stumbled.

From the sample code at a youtube video, I created a complete code set and posted to
FB dev forum, the err msg I get is,
"FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()"

Here's the link of my code,
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=94801

Note:
We could use a simple HTML page for testing this...

What's wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source from my project's facebook test page, containing complete implementations of a few common facebook tasks.  The only thing redacted is the facebook app ID.  Obviously, you don't have our libs but in this case they just verify the session and draw headers.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>phyre Lux Client</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../phyrelib-clientside.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/phyre.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

                <script src="js/typeface.js"></script> 
                <script src="js/cicle_fina.typeface.js"></script> 
                </head> 
                <body onLoad='return 0;' id='luxDocBody' class='phyremodule'> 

<div id='fb-root'></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
FB.init({appId: 'REDACTED', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
      // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
    alert('yay');
    } else {
      // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
    alert('nay');
    }
  });

FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
     attachment: {
       name: 'Connect',
       caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
       description: (
         'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
         'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
         'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
       ),
       href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js'
     },
     action_links: [
       { text: 'Code', href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js' }
     ],
     user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
    alert('yay');
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
    alert('nay');
  }
});
</script> 
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I tweaked it into a plain HTML file, now, I get err msg e.root is undefined
[Break On This Error] FB.provide('Content',{_root:null,_hidd...it();a.parentNode.removeChild(a);}});
all.js (line 6

Comment: I omitted the luxFooter(); funciton.  Just added it still same error.

Comment: all the js code is inside HEAD tag and <body>
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>

<div id='fb-root'></div>
</body>

Comment: @Test: Oh heck, my bad.  I knew I was forgetting something!  I'm editing my answer to include that JS now.

Comment: @Test: Okay, I just copied everything from the PHP's output - read, by viewing it in browser.  And yeah, the JS is inside the body, that's ridiculous - it is however I assure you how the facebook docs told me to do it.

Comment: Great.  We're much closer.  Upon FB login, I got this err msg (id fake here, for my actual code it is real: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?api_key=100001125873988&app_id=100001125873988&display=popup&fbconnect=1&locale=en_US&method=permissions.request&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D0%23cb%3Df3491dd47a051d6%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F127.0.0.1%253A8600%252Ff10840c96c50fa%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df1664c84d598c4e%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&return_session=1&sdk=joey&session_version=3

Comment: ahe, could it be that it requires some sort of Extended Permission something? thanks.

Comment: ...Bizarre, it works fine on my server.  I'd suggest checking your app permissions, it's all kind of convoluted.  Make sure your app key is actually allowed to post to walls.

Comment: "Make sure your app key is actually allowed to post to walls", what do you mean by that?  thanks.

Comment: hmm... I just created a new fb test account, tried with ff3.6, ie9 and chrome10, still same prob.

Comment: As I recall I had the opportunity to make an app key OR a site key, and they were different in ways that were more or less opaque to my intellect.  I merely mean that given Facebook's complexity it's entirely possible that your key can't do what it SHOULD be able to do.

Comment: @Test Huh.  If you want I can let you try my implementation.  It's possible that for some reason my solution only works for... me.  Or something.